# Аннотировать фильтр к запросу

Tags: python, django

Есть две модели:

```
class Writer(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(length=40)

class Book(models.Model):
    Author= models.ForeignKey(Writer)
    Title = models.CharField(length=40)
```

Во view я получаю автора по Name:

```
author=Writer.objects.filter(Name=name)
```

Если я сделаю `author.book_set.all()`, то это будет уже отдельный запрос к бд?

Как я могу к автору приаттачить написанные им книги в том же запросе?

Comment: а `Name` и `Author` это одно значение ?

Comment: Нет, Name = Это поле CharField, а Author - это поле-связь к модели Writer

Answer (score 0):

Для подгрузки связанных данных существуют `select_related` и `prefetch_related`. Первый подгружает объекты, связанные через FK, второй для прочих ситуаций, в т.ч. когда не помогает первый. Более подробно можете почитать [в документации об обоих методах](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.select_related).

А что касается решения, то вам надо написать так

```
author = Writer.objects.filter(Name=name).prefetch_related('book_set') # поправьте, если ошибся в названии
```

либо

```
books = Book.objects.select_related('author').filter(author__Name=name)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Если я сделаю author.book_set.all(), то это будет уже отдельный запрос к бд?

Да, и для каждого автора будет выполняться отдельный запрос к БД. Это типичный случай "[N+1 selects problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-the-n1-selects-problem-in-orm-object-relational-mapping)"

```
>>> for author in Writer.objects.all():
...     print(author.book_set.all())
... 
(0.000) SELECT "so_writer"."id", "so_writer"."Name" FROM "so_writer"; args=()
(0.000) SELECT "so_book"."id", "so_book"."Author_id", "so_book"."Title" FROM "so_book" WHERE "so_book"."Author_id" = 1  LIMIT 21; args=(1,)
<QuerySet []>
(0.000) SELECT "so_book"."id", "so_book"."Author_id", "so_book"."Title" FROM "so_book" WHERE "so_book"."Author_id" = 2  LIMIT 21; args=(2,)
<QuerySet []>
(0.000) SELECT "so_book"."id", "so_book"."Author_id", "so_book"."Title" FROM "so_book" WHERE "so_book"."Author_id" = 3  LIMIT 21; args=(3,)
<QuerySet []>
```

> Как я могу к автору приаттачить написанные им книги в том же запросе?

Во-первых, определиться с задачей: нужны ли вам какие-то данные об авторе книг (помимо его id). Если нет, и нужно просто выбрать книги только одного автора:

```
>>> print(Book.objects.filter(Author__Name="dmitriy"))
(0.000) SELECT "so_book"."id", "so_book"."Author_id", "so_book"."Title" FROM "so_book" INNER JOIN "so_writer" ON ("so_book"."Author_id" = "so_writer"."id") WHERE "so_writer"."Name" = 'dmitriy'  LIMIT 21; args=('dmitriy',)
<QuerySet []>
```

Если же нужны данные об авторе для каждой книги или список книг для каждого автора, то

```
>>> authors = Writer.objects.prefetch_related("book_set")
>>> for author in authors:
...     print(author.book_set.all())
... 
(0.001) SELECT "so_writer"."id", "so_writer"."Name" FROM "so_writer"; args=()
(0.000) SELECT "so_book"."id", "so_book"."Author_id", "so_book"."Title" FROM "so_book" WHERE "so_book"."Author_id" IN (1, 2, 3); args=(1, 2, 3)
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet []>
<QuerySet []>
```

либо

```
>>> books = Book.objects.select_related("Author")
>>> for book in books.all():
...     print(book.Author.Name)
... 
(0.000) SELECT "so_book"."id", "so_book"."Author_id", "so_book"."Title", "so_writer"."id", "so_writer"."Name" FROM "so_book" INNER JOIN "so_writer" ON ("so_book"."Author_id" = "so_writer"."id"); args=()
1
2
```

Об отличиях этих двух подходов можно прочитать на https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related. Если кратко, `select_related` - только для ForeignKey, но работает, как правило, быстрее; `prefetch_related` - универсальнее (делает prefetch для reversed foreignkey, m2m, [позволяет большую кастомизацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.Prefetch)), но медленнее.